# in app-Admin.php fatalerror: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script

Tags: laravel-5

in app-Admin.php fatalerror: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script

Comment: Please post your script (or a least the first few lines of it)

Comment: this is my files i hope to get any help please

Comment: put namespace your-name-space; at the begining of your file i.e just below <?php